# find connectivity

Tags: functions

Imagine a chain of 20 rings, labeled by 1-20 sequentially. We want to make random size sets of numbers randomly chosen from these 1-20 rings. No duplicate numbers are allowed.

Example of a set: $\{16,7,11\}$.

We want to count the links between the members of different sets. Rules:

1. If we have got one number $N$ in set $A$ and next successive number $N+1$ exists in set $B$ this is called link of length $1$.
2. If the next successive number $N+1$ is not member of any set, we look for the closest successive number $N+m$ existing in other sets, so this is called a link of length $m$.
3. If the next successive number is also in the set $A$, then is a loop, we ignore it.
4. The two ends of the chain, if not member of any set, are dangled, we ignore it.

Output = {the number of links of length i}.

Example:

```
clusters = {{2,3,4}, {16,7,11}, {9,20,12,18}}
```

In `clusters` we have:

1 link of length 1 : `11-12`

3 links of length 2 : `16-17-18, 7-8-9, 9-10-11`

1 link of length 3 : `4-5-6-7`

1 link of length 4: `12-13-14-15-16`

and `18-19-20` is a loop to same cluster and `1` is a free end so ignore them.

How can I count the links to have:

```
out1 = {{1,length1}, {3,length2}, {1,length3}, {1,length4}}
```

Also we need to know the total number of links between two given cluster. for above example we will have:

```
out2 = {{cluster1-2, 1links},{cluster2-3, 5links},{cluster1-3,0links}}
```

Comment: I"m afraid that your question is not comprehensible as stated. Maybe if you provide a small sample of the input and what you wish the output to be, it would help clarify.

Comment: Should we assume no repeats (NO connectivity = 0 ? )

Comment: yes, no connection=0

Comment: Now it makes sense !..

Comment: is this still unclear? I see it is on hold

Comment: No it's still not clear - you state that 5 is not in any cluster and then say it is in 1 link of length 3.

Comment: as I said a chain of 20 numbers" all 20 numbers exist. only some collapsed into clusters. imagine a chain of 20 rings that some rings are glued together (clusters) the rest are still there linking these clusters. numbers are id each every ring.

Comment: please let me know if the question is still unclear. I had it read by couple of people here and it is completely clear to them.
thanks

Comment: I have reopened this question because I believe I understand everything except "and 18-19-20 is a loop to same cluster" -- is that chain eliminated because it is at the end (20) or for another reason?

Comment: yes 20 is end of the chain. and this is the reason that chain eliminated.

however, 18-19-20 is a sequence but since 18 and 20 are in the same set, this is not link but loop. which we ignore.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  This is a good challenge to do efficiently.

Comment: Please see my answer.  I keep making mistakes but I think I'm getting close.  Please test my function and tell me how it goes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Since only you seem to have understood the question, could you perhaps take a shot at editing it (completely) and include a small example? Perhaps if it were clearer, we'd have some more answers/attempts.

Comment: @rm-rf Iff Sesna confirms that I *did* understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Third try; here is a different method that I believe is equivalent but which should be *much* better performing.  *Now with additional optimizations for a threefold increase in performance.*

```
links3[{}] := {}

links3[clusters : {{__Integer} ..}?(Min@# > 0 &)] :=
  Module[{x, pair, uni},
    uni = Union @@ clusters;
    x = ConstantArray[0, Last @ uni];
    MapIndexed[(x[[#]] = #2[[1]]) &, clusters];
    pair = Partition[#, 2, 1] &;
    pair[uni][[ SparseArray[pair[ x[[uni]] ].{-1, 1}] @ "AdjacencyLists" ]]
  ]

links3[{{2, 3, 4}, {16, 7, 11}, {9, 20, 12, 18}}]
```

> ```
> {{4, 7}, {7, 9}, {9, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 16}, {16, 18}}
> ```

This explicitly outputs the *link* intervals so you can check them.  To tally use:

```
count[{}] := {0}
count[a : {{_, _} ..}] := Sort @ Tally[a.{-1, 1}]

count @ links3[{{2, 3, 4}, {16, 7, 11}, {9, 20, 12, 18}}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}}
> ```

Note that [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tally.html) gives the counts in the form {*link-length*, *occurrences*}; this can be reversed if necessary.

Comment: As usual, such a pretty answer. Might want to enforce elements are positive, else if say there's a zero you'll replace the head with the sublist index. Still works though... +1

Comment: @rasher Thank you.  We have yet to confirm that it's what the OP needs however.  The argument test was an afterthought, and perhaps a half-hearted one; you're right, if I was going to include it I should have made it robust.

Comment: thanks. this last (third) one works excellent. except when all numbers are member of one list (0 link) Tally gives error of course.

Comment: @Sesna I'm glad I understood you.  I may edit the question tomorrow to add an alternative description since apparently a lot of people did not.  Regarding the empty set (`{}`), if that is a problem in practice you could modify `count` to handle it, e.g.:  `count[{}] := {{0}} (* or whatever else you want *); count[a : {{_, _} ..}] := Sort @ Tally[a.{-1, 1}];`

Comment: sorry I couldn't get this working. could you explain how does it work?

Comment: @Sesna What isn't working?  The entire thing, or only the `count` part?  Perhaps I didn't understand after all, or failed to think this through.

Comment: Entire code is working perfectly. only modified count doesn't.
if `list={}` then count out is `count[links[{}]]`

Comment: @Sesna Ah, I see.  I thought you meant a case like `links3[{{3,4,5}}]` which returns `{}`.  What output or message do you desire for both that case, and the case of `links3[{}]`?

Comment: this is already fine for my purposes. but I'm curious how can I get `count out = {0}` when `list={}`

Comment: @Sesna I modified the functions as requested.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for clean previous answers. do you have any suggestion for the last part of my question?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the first step for you..

```
 list = {{7, 2}, {3, 1}, {9, 4, 15, 23}}

 Total@((Count[Tuples[#] , {x_, y_} /; Abs[x - y] == 1 ]) & /@ 
         Subsets[list, {2}])

-> 3
```

Edit.. based on revision.

Sorry i don't have mathematica here to work this out exactly, but you can use this framework with the Count criteria something like:

```
    ( Abs[x-y]==n && Union[Flatten@list,Range[Min[{x,y}]+1,Max[{x,y}]-1]]=={} )
```

Then wrap the whole works in

```
    maxpos = (Max[#]-Min[#])&@Flatten@list
    Table[ .. , {n, maxpos}]
```

Edit..that should have been `Intersection`..

```
 list = {{2, 3, 4}, {16, 7, 11}, {9, 20, 12, 18}}
 maxpos = (Max[#] - Min[#]) &@Flatten@list
 Select[ Table[ {n, 
    Total@((Count[
         Tuples[#], {x_, y_} /;(
           Abs[x - y] == n && 
           Intersection[
             Flatten@list, 
             Range[Min[{x, y}] + 1, Max[{x, y}] - 1]] == {} )
                ]) & /@ Subsets[list, {2}])} , {n, maxpos}], #[[2]] != 0 &]

   ---> {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}}
```

Perhaps more efficiently find valid links then Tally based on length:

```
   -Subtract @@ # & /@ 
         Select[ Sort /@ Flatten[Tuples[#] & /@ Subsets[list, {2}], 1]  , 
         Intersection[
           Flatten@list, 
           Range[#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]] - 1]] == {} &
         ] // Tally // Sort

   ---> {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}}
```

Comment: sorry I didn't get this. and doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try as I might, your question is pretty indecipherable. I urge you to clean it up, add some concrete examples and rules of what a 'connection' is, exclusion rules, etc. Nonetheless, the following will generate a list of all pairs matched in the sublists along with their corresponding 'distance'. Perhaps you can use its output to accomplish what you want.

```
list = {{7, 2}, {3, 1}, {9, 4, 15, 23}};

Flatten[Outer[{{##}, Abs[#1 - #2]} &, #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
  Subsets[list, {2}], 2]

(*
{{{7, 3}, 4}, {{7, 1}, 6}, {{2, 3}, 1}, {{2, 1}, 1}, {{7, 9}, 2}, 
{{7, 4}, 3}, {{7, 15}, 8}, {{7, 23}, 16}, {{2, 9}, 7}, {{2, 4}, 2},
{{2, 15}, 13}, {{2, 23}, 21}, {{3, 9}, 6}, {{3, 4}, 1}, 
{{3, 15}, 12}, {{3, 23}, 20}, {{1, 9}, 8}, {{1, 4}, 3}, 
{{1, 15}, 14}, {{1, 23}, 22}}
*)
```

Comment: sorry for unclear question. edited.

Comment: @SesnaSecna: I'm afraid that edit made the question even *more* ambiguous. This is an *awesome* community, you'll find members *really* want to help and educate, but they can't if the question is nebulous. How about you post a small but real example, say using 50 numbers split into sublists, and show what the precise end result should be and *explain* the mechanism / rules / etc. that gets to it. Then someone can help you build the MM code to do it.

Comment: @SesnaSecna: tell me this - if the list were say `{{7, 2}, {10, 1}, {5, 9, 4, 15, 23}}`, is the expected output `{2, 3, 1, 0, 1}`?

Comment: no, the expected output for this list is:
2 length1; 3length2; 1 length5; so:
    `{{2,1},{3,2},{1,5}}`

I also edited the question with example. hope it's clear this time. sorry or being annoying beginner.

Comment: @SesnaSecna: that is not how your question had the output formatted, but OK, give me a moment to rework code...

Comment: @SesnaSecna:NVM, this has become yet again such a different interpretation, I've spent enough time already on the earlier OP edits and their possible interpretations. Your current one is a much easier problem, I'm sure someone else will pick up the gauntlet. In the future, please be more concise, yet detailed, in your questions & examples: it will save others time and possible frustration.

Comment: and I wish I find a way to learn mm tricks good. the syntaxes and examples in documentation sucks. what  you guys write here is way different than what one can learn from HELP!
any ways, thanks for your time

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12667/discussion-between-sesna-secna-and-rasher)